# IE7 Ignoring styles in standards mode, but look great in Quirks mode

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I'm having an issue where IE 7 styles look mostly correct in Quirks mode, but in Standards mode it is ignoring or not seeing many of the styles. The quirks mode version looks much closer to the way it looks in Chrome and Firefox.

**UPDATE**

I found that the file had a syntax error in the CSS file which was causing everything below that point in the CSS to be ignored by IE 7.

Answer (score 0):

IE 7 renders web files differently than other browsers (so does the other version of IE).

To fixed that, you need to use css hack for each IE versions:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="styles/ie7_styles.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="styles/ie8_styles.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="styles/ie9_styles.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I'm aware of the browser differences, but I'm not sure why IE 7 quirks mode looks much closer to the modern browsers than does the IE 7 Standards/Strict mode.